# Cypress fixtures - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'runTests')

Tags: mysql, node.js, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I am trying to connect to mysql in cypress test cases. But getting an error on when trying to import file `mysql-db-connect.js` in steps definition file.

**mysql-db-connect.js**

```
function queryTestDb(query, pool) {

    // creates a new mysql connection using credentials from cypress.json env's
    const connection = createPool.createConnection(pool)
    // start connection to db
    connection.connect()
    // exec query + disconnect to db as a Promise
     return  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
            if (error) reject(error)
            else {
                connection.end()
                // console.log(results)
                return resolve(results)
            }
        })
    })

module.exports={queryTestDb}
queryTestDb("select * from test LIMIT 5", pool).then(res => console.log(res));
```

Above `queryTestDb()` code works perfectly when execute from same file.

But throws an error when trying to import and run steps definition file

**Step definition format**

```
///<reference types="cypress" />
import { Before,After,Given, When, Then, And } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";
import{closeTabs} from '../../../support/utility/tearDown.js';

import {queryTestDb} from '../../../support/utility/mysql-db-connect.js';   ---> ///getting error on this line 

const pool = {host: "xxxx",  user: "xxxx", password: "xxxx",  database: "main", connectionLimit:10  } 

 Given("connecting to db", function(){

         queryTestDb("select * from test LIMIT 5", pool).then(res => console.log(res));     
})
```

Comment: I am also facing similar issue kindly let me know if you got any solution